# Php - Combining lines of a single array with same values

Tags: php, arrays

Basically I have this array:

```
$foo[0] = array("name" => "A", "apples" => "2");
$foo[1] = array("name" => "B", "apples" => "4");
$foo[2] = array("name" => "C", "apples" => "6");
$foo[3] = array("name" => "A", "apples" => "3");
$foo[4] = array("name" => "B", "apples" => "5");
$foo[5] = array("name" => "C", "apples" => "7");
```

And I want this:

```
$foo[0] = array("name" => "A", "apple1" => "2", "apple2" => "3");
$foo[1] = array("name" => "B", "apple1" => "4", "apple2" => "5");
$foo[2] = array("name" => "C", "apple1" => "6", "apple2" => "7");
```

Comment: Well, what's keeping you?

Comment: Would make more sense like: `$foo[0] = array("name" => "A", "apples" => array("2", "3"));`

Comment: And what did you try so far to reach yoar goal?

Comment: I can't write a function to convert one array in the other

Comment: I tried nested foreach... usort... going crazy

Comment: Well yeah, I can see how it would be difficult :) You've got a key named `apples` and you want it changed to `apple1` and `apple2`. I would heavily consider @AbraCadaver's suggestion

Comment: thanks @AbraCadaver and IsThisJavascript I'll try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the *classic* `foreach` loop:

```
$foo[0] = array("name" => "A", "apples" => "2");
$foo[1] = array("name" => "B", "apples" => "4");
$foo[2] = array("name" => "C", "apples" => "6");
$foo[3] = array("name" => "A", "apples" => "3");
$foo[4] = array("name" => "B", "apples" => "5");
$foo[5] = array("name" => "C", "apples" => "7");

$result = array();
foreach( $foo as $value ) {
    if ( !isset( $result[ $value[ "name" ] ] ) ) {
        $result[ $value[ "name" ] ] = array();
        $result[ $value[ "name" ] ][ "name" ] = $value[ "name" ];
        $result[ $value[ "name" ] ][ "apple1" ] = $value[ "apples" ];
    } else {
        $cnt = count( $result[ $value[ "name" ] ] );
        $result[ $value[ "name" ] ][ "apple" . $cnt ] = $value[ "apples" ];
    }
}

//returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.
$result = array_values( $result );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => A
            [apple1] => 2
            [apple2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => B
            [apple1] => 4
            [apple2] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => C
            [apple1] => 6
            [apple2] => 7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using arrays, then use arrays instead of numbered strings like:

```
$foo[0] = array("name" => "A", "apples" => array("2", "3"));
```

Loop and index the result by the `name` value and dynamically append the `apples` value to the `apples` array:

```
foreach($foo as $v) {
    $result[$v['name']]['name'] = $v['name'];
    $result[$v['name']]['apples'][] = $v['apples'];
}
```

Then if needed to re-index:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these results from a database?

If so you could probably do this in one line with some combination of the PDO constants: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_UNIQUE

I'd look at `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` or `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`, they can also be combined like so `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_GROUP`

If not then the query itself may also be able to yield this information with `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yes this array is the result of a dirty union of three queries... Thank you for this suggestion, actually I'm using php / mysql at a very basic level and I need to deliver this project as soon as possible. Later I will take time to explore more elegant solutions!